# Modules evaluated multiple times with CommonChunk plugin in webpack

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have a webpack build with multiple entries and one common chunk. Sometime I load `entry1` sometimes I load `entry1` and `entry2`, sometimes entries 2 and 3. In any case I always include the common chunk.

Everything seems fine, the bundled files are fine. But it seems there is a problem at runtime. When I need two entries and they both depend on some module (that is in the common file). This module is evaluated twice.

Simple example:

entry1.js

```
require('./dep.js');
```

entry2.js

```
require('./dep.js');
```

deps.js

```
alert('called')
module.exports = 2;
```

Here I see the alert called twice. I was expecting webpack to do something similar as `node.js` and cache the require.

I double checked and the content of `deps.js` is indeed in the `common.js` file and by placing a breakpoint on the `alert` shows that the same code is called multiple times. Which is not expected.

Is there a way to solve this ?

Answer (score 4):

If this is webpack 4, you should use [optimization.runtimeChunk: 'single`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/optimization/#optimizationruntimechunk) just like suggested in the documentation. Otherwise modules are initialized every time as per the docs:

> Imported modules are initialized for each runtime chunk separately, so if you include multiple entry points on a page, beware of this behavior. You will probably want to set it to single or use another configuration that allows you to only have one runtime instance.

Comment: I did this and code is not being executed now, no error on the page though and I can see the files are loaded, any idea why?

Comment: Ok I figured it out

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with vue cli MPA (multi page app)

I solved by adding 'runtime' to the list of chunks of each page in addition to the solution given by @Herz3h

Here is what `vue.config.js` should look like

```js
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    page1: {
      entry: 'src/pages/1/main.js',
      chunks: [
        'chunk-vendors',
        'chunk-common',
        'runtime', //Make sure you add this in your chunks
        'page1',
      ]
    }
  },
  configureWebpack() {
    return {
      optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: 'single',
      },
    }
  }
}
```